# How would I merge nested dictionaries so that the keys are different but values are updated

Tags: python, dictionary

How would I merge 2 dictionaries but delete what is different from the dictionary or update it. For example:

```py
account = {
    "1": {"name": "bob", "age": "20", "work": "Assistant"},
    "2": {"name": "James", "age": "36", "work": "Dev"},
}

accounts = {
    "bob": {"name": "bob", "age": "25", "work": "Dev"},
    "James": {"name": "James", "age": "40", "work": "Assistant"},
}
```

Leaving me with an expected dictionary:

```py
account = {
    "1": {"name": "bob", "age": "25", "work": "Dev"},
    "2": {"name": "James", "age": "40", "work": "Assistant"},
}
```

I am trying to update dictionaries with 2 different keys but the same values. So that no keys are the same but the values are.
Any suggestions?

Comment: your syntax does not look very clear in the code part tbh, can you be a little bit more specific with your expected output please?

Comment: Your account and accounts json are incorrect. Please validate and fix.

Comment: Welcome to SO Bond 007, I split the code you wrote into different lines so that you can see clearer the syntax errors that there are. You are missing commas, colons (`:`) and you have some extra opening curly brackets (`{`). Vishal Singh has edited after me correcting those syntax errors, so you should be able to see them easily in the last edit.

Comment: sorry for those errors

Comment: This is unclear. According to what should the merge be done? Key in account? Value for name? Are they supposed to be the same? Are the same fields present in both dicts? Please clarify.

Comment: As a side note, please always make sure that you are free to answer any request for clarification or question in the next half-hour or so after asking a question...

Comment: keys are different but values are the same but I want to update the values from one dictionary to the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this uses dictionary comprehension to make a new dictionary by iterating over the dictionary `account` and checking if the `name` associated with each `id` exists in the `accounts` and if it does replace it with the value of `name` from `accounts`  otherwise keep the same value.

```
account = {key: accounts.get(value["name"], value) for key, value in account.items()}
```

Comment: give me 20 minutes and I will test this. Thanks though

Comment: I think he is quite new to Python so maybe explaining what each step does  would help him understand(iterating over account pairs, searching for the same name in accounts, defaulting to the previous value if not found, ...)

Comment: No its not that I understand the code but I have something to do so will be back in a moment.

Comment: My comment was general, not related to the 20 mins you asked for. Providing that info would make this answer easier to understand by those that find it when googling for something similar.

Comment: Ok sorry for that. I am back

Comment: @Adirio added the explanation. I hope it suffices.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this package `jict`

```
from jict import jict

jct = jict({"1":{"name":"bob","age":"20","work":"Assistant"}})
jct2 = jict({"2":{"name":"James","age":"36","work":"Dev"}})

jct.replace({"name":"bob","age":"25","work":"Dev"})
jct2.replace({"name": "James", "age": "40", "work": "Assistant"})

print(jct)
# {
#   "1": {
#     "name": "bob",
#     "age": "25",
#     "work": "Dev"
#  }
# }

print(jct2)
# {
#   "2": {
#    "name": "James",
#    "age": "40",
#    "work": "Assistant"
#  }
# }
```

install `pip install jict`

Comment: I dont have access to pip at where I am planning to show them this but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: What is the reason to suggest to use `jict` if you are not using anything a normal `dict` doesn't have?

Comment: I don't think a normal dict has a multilevel replace method

Comment: It is called update not replace, I'm not sure if the behavior is 100% the same as I don't know `jict` taht well but what you did in this answer can be done (just change `replace` for `update` and remove the `jict()` calls at the start and it works)

Comment: dict update function replaces all the content in the key, jict replace replaces the content in a key ```if the subkeys match```

Comment: `dict.update` only updates the provided keys, the rest are left untouched: `a = {1: 0, 2: 0}; a.update({2: 1, 3: 1})` outputs `a = {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 1}`

Comment: Ok, the example was not well explained, take a look now... can you do the same?